# Counter within django loop

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have the following django / html code:

```
{% for x in fixtures %}

    <div id="match1" style="display:block">{{x.home_team.teamname}}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

The above simply displays all teams from a set of fixtures.  It works perfectly as it stands.  However, I would like the div id to go up 1 each time it runs through the loop.  I.e "match1" then "match2" then "match3" etc.

I am assuming javascript is my friend here? but some direction would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for javascript. You can use the `forloop.counter` variable:

```
{% for x in fixtures %}

    <div id="match{{ forloop.counter }}" style="display:block">{{x.home_team.teamname}}</div>

{% endfor %}
```

The various variables available in a for loop are described in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

Comment: That was easier than expected!  Sorry.